# Finding a 2-chain whose boundary is $c - c_{1, n}$ for a 1-cube $c$ such that $c(0) = c(1)$ and a circle $c_{1, n}$.

Tags: analysis

**Problem (Spivak, 4-24).** Define $c_{1, n} : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $c_{1, n}(t) = (\cos 2\pi nt, \sin 2\pi nt)$.  If $c$ is a singular 1-cube in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{ 0 \}$ with $c(0) = c(1)$, show that there is an integer $n$ and a 2-chain $c^2$ such that $c - c_{1, n} = \partial c^2$.

**Answer attempt.**  Define a singular 2-cube $c^2$ by
$$ c^2(x, k) = kc_{1, n}(x) + (1-k)c(x). $$
Using the definition of the boundary of a singular 2-cube,
$$\begin{align*}\partial c^2(t) &= -c^2(0, t) + c^2(1, t) + c^2(t, 0) - c^2(t, 1)
\\
&= -[tc_{1, n}(0) + (1-t)c(0)] + [tc_{1, n}(1) + (1-t)c(1)] + c(t) - c_{1, n}(t)
\\
&= c(t) - c_{1, n}(t).
\end{align*}$$

The terms in brackets cancel out because $c(0) = c(1)$ and $c_{1, n}(0) = c_{1, n}(1)$.  I know that this answer is wrong, but I don't know why.

I've seen this question asked with the additional requirement that $c^2$ be in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{ 0 \}$, but I don't see how that could change anything.  I could simply replace $c^2$ with $b^2$, where $b^2 = c^2 + v$ for a large enough vector $v$.  The expression for the boundary of $b^2$ would be the same as that for the boundary of $c^2$, except that $v$ would show up four times: twice with a positive sign and twice with a negative sign.  So $\partial b^2 = \partial c^2$.

Comment: Oops, sorry!  You're right; I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is wrong because it's possible for $c_{1,n}(t) = -c(t)$; when this happens, you get a cube in $\mathbb R^2$, but not in $\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,0\}$.

For the case where there's no restriction on the target (i.e, you get to use the whole plane), your answer is more or less correct... except that your particular 2-chain has four boundary pieces: the arc $c_{1,n}$, the segment from $c_{1,n}(0)$ to $c(0)$, the arc $c$ traversed backwards, and the segment from $c(1)$ to $c_{1,n}(1)$.

Now those two segments are in fact opposites, but you did traverse each of them.

The problem is that you sort of HAVE to do so, unless you make the additional assumption that $c(0) = (1,0)$ (which is  $c_{1,n}(0)$). I can't recall how Spivak defines the boundary operator and what cancellations he allows, so this is sort of all I can say on this for now.

The assumption that the target space is to be the *punctured* plane is what makes this problem interesting, by the way. In the plane, $c_{1,k}$ and $c_{1,p}$ form the boundary of a 2-chain (the one you described!) for any $k$ and $p$. But in the punctured plane, you have to have $k = p$ for this to happen (i.e, there's a particular value of $n$ that works for your curve $c$, and all others will fail). That number $n$ is "how many times $c$ winds counterclockwise around the origin."

To continue the story a bit:

In another problem, Spivak defines a 1-form on the punctured plane and calls it $d\theta$, which is a rotten name, because there's no function $\theta$ whose exterior derivative is that 1-form, but it's traditional.

From here on, I want to assume that $c(0) = (1,0)$, so that $c$ and each of the $c_{1,k}$ start and end at the same point.

Now if you compute
$$
h(t) = \int_0^t c^{*}d\theta
$$
for each $t$ from $0$ to $1$, you get a function with $h(0) = 0$ and $h(1) = n$ for some $n$. And it's THAT particular $n$ that you should choose for $c_{1,n}$.

What makes $h$ so special? The fact that 
$$
c(t) = (\cos h(t), \sin h(t))
$$
i.e., that $h$ is the "angle" of the point $c(t)$ from the $x$-axis. (This takes a bit of proving, but not too much.)

The corresponding function
$$
k(t) = \int_0^t c_{1,n}^{*}d\theta
$$
is just 
$$
k(t) = nt.
$$

Now you can define
$$
H(s, t) = (1-s) h(t) + s k(t)
$$
and define
$$
c_2(s, t) = (\cos H(s,t), \sin H(s, t))
$$
and $c_2$ is a 2-chain whose boundary is exactly $c - c_{1,n}$.

Comment: how can we assume that $c$ lies in the unit circle? Is it obvious that $c$ and $c/|c|$ have the same winding number?

Comment: Here's a homotopy from $c$ to $c/|c|$: let $H(s, t) = \frac{c(t)}{(1-s) \cdot 1 + s \cdot |c(t)|}$. Because both $1$ and $|c(t)|$ are positive, the image of $H$ (for any $s$ lies in the punctured plane. Essentially, $H$ is just "slide between $c$ and $c/|c|$ by moving radially". Anyhow, that shows that they have the same winding number (it's a discrete-valued, continuous function of $s$).